# Construct an exactly smooth function as a cutoff of half ball with vanishing normal dirivative

Tags: analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

$\newcommand{\pt}{\partial}$
Suppose $B_r^+:=\{x=(x_1,x_2)\in B_r(0)\subset R^2|x_2\geq0\}$, can we construct a $C^\infty$ smooth function $\phi$, $0\leq\phi\leq1$, such that
$$
\phi\equiv1 \text{ in }B_1,\quad\phi\equiv 0 \text{ in }R^{2+}\setminus B_2^+,\quad \frac{\pt\phi}{\pt x_2}=0,\quad \forall x_2=0.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $g\in C^\infty[0,\infty)$ such that $g=1$ on $[0,1)$, $g=0$ outside of $[0,2)$ and $0\leq g\leq 1$. Define $\phi(x)=g(|x|)$, then $\partial_{x_2} \phi(x_1, 0)$ is just the tangential derivative on a circle of radius $|x_1|$ and center $0$, which is zero since our function is radial.